# Torque/Maui Custer

Tags: google-compute-engine

I have a Torque/Maui cluster with NFS and i'm trying to do something similar with GCE. I am working with gent4 that I have to preinstall it in each node or create an image for al nodes. 
I do not know how to do something similar with GCE. In aws I have found starcluster with it works perfectly.

Any Ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a opensource project which I have routinely used to spin clusters of different kind and supports different clouds.

http://gc3-uzh-ch.github.io/elasticluster/

Comment: glad I could be of some help :)